# Logstash-output-jms ignores codec

Tags: logstash, jms, logstash-configuration

Trying to use logstash-output-jms to inject some messages from stdin.

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => plain {
      format => "%{message}"
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => plain { format => "%{message}" } }
  jms {
    codec => plain { format => "%{message}" }
    pub_sub => false
    destination => "TOPIC_A"
    yaml_file => "conf.yml"
    yaml_section => "wmq"
  }
}
```

When I run this config and input `<A>aaa</a>` I see displayed in the console the exact same message but when it publishes to MQ, it looks like the message itself contains also the envelope.

```
input {
  jms {
    destination => "TOPIC_A"
    yaml_file => "conf.yml"
    yaml_section => "wmq"
    include_headers => false
    include_properties => false
    include_body => true
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug {}}
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
  "@timestamp" => 2022-02-01T07:35:34.783Z,
  "@version" => "1",
  "message" => "{\"@timestamp\":\"2022-02-01T07:35:04.481Z\",\"message\":\"<A>aaa</A>\",\"@version\":\"1\",\"host\":\"host.com\"}",
}
```

The message also contains some meta information, like timestamp, version and host.

What I expected would be something like:

```
{
  "@timestamp" => 2022-02-01T07:35:34.783Z,
  "@version" => "1",
  "message" => "<A>aaa</A>",
}
```

Even if I change or remove at all the content of codec within output.jms there is no difference, that's why it seems ignored.

Logstash version: logstash 6.6.0

Logstash-output-jms plugin version: 3.0.4

Logstash-code-plain version: 3.1.0

Comment: I don't think this plugin supports the `codec` option, it also seems to be abandoned as the last update was 4 years ago. I was only able to find the [documentation](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-jms/blob/main/docs/index.asciidoc) on Github and there is no mention to supporting codecs.

Comment: I think you're right. I was under the impression that codec-json and codec-plain are supported, since they are dependencies here: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-jms/blob/main/logstash-output-jms.gemspec . Is there any other way I can publish to MQ the XML directly without the envelope?

Comment: Not that I know, I do not use MQ, but if it is something that can work with the STOMP protocol, you have a [logstash-output-stomp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-stomp.html) plugin.